# Connecting to tokio-native-tls echo.rs from react

Tags: reactjs, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, rust-tokio

I upgraded my react front end to use https. That broke the connection to my backend tokio socket server. I tried to run a test against the tokio-native-tls echo.rs example which uses an identity.p12 file after I ran these commands:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in identity.p12 -nocerts -out .conf/server.key
openssl pkcs12 -in identity.p12 -clcerts -nokeys -out server.crt
openssl rsa -in server.key -out .conf/server_d.key
SSL_CRT_FILE=.cert/server.crt
SSL_KEY_FILE=.cert/server_d.key
HTTPS=true
```

Front end runs under nginx which I configured to use https.

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'accept error: Ssl(Error { code: ErrorCode(1), cause: Some(Ssl(ErrorStack([Error
```

{ code: 336151574, library: "SSL routines", function: "ssl3_read_bytes",
reason: "sslv3 alert certificate unknown", file: "../ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c",
line: 1528, data: "SSL alert number 46" }]))) },
X509VerifyResult { code: 0, error: "ok" })', tokio-native-tls/examples/echo.rs:33:34

I'm having trouble configuring the react client with the server using that identity.p12 file.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: UPDATE:
I succeeded in getting the rust socket server to attempt a handshake with my react client. 
The rust server reports a successfu handshake, but the read following the tls_acceptor.accept call returns unprocessed negotation data which should have been used during the handshake.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue by combining the echo example from https://github.com/tokio-rs/tls and https://github.com/snapview/tokio-tungstenite.
This addressed both the http and tls requirements.